# html initialize selectbox issue

Tags: jquery, html, select

I have 3 select boxes

```
<select name="comp" id="comp">
<option value="" disabled selected>Select company</option>
<option value="Company1">Company1</option>
<option value="Company2">Company2</option>
</select>

<select name="dept" id="dept">
<option value="" disabled selected>Select department</option>
<option value="All">All</option>
<option ng-repeat="department in departmentList" value="{{department}}">{{department}}</option>
</select>

<select name="staff" id="staff">
<option value="" disabled selected>Select staff</option>
<option value="All">All</option>
<option ng-repeat="staff in staffList" value="{{staff}}">{{staff}}</option>
</select>
```

if the first selectbox changes its value then i want to reset the 2nd and 3rd selectbox

```
$("#comp").change(function() {
    $('#dept').val(''); 
    $('#staff').val('');

});
```

If the second selectbox changes it's value then i want to reset only the 3rd selectbox

```
$("#dept").change(function() {
        $('#staff').val('');
});
```

My problem is that when i set a value in the 3rd selectBox and then change the first selectbox then it should reset the 2nd and 3rd selectbox by doing

```
$('#dept').val(''); 
$('#staff').val('');
```

but actually it adds a blank item in the list of the 3rd selectbox

```
<option value="? string:staff name ?"></option> ==$0
```

Why this item is added to the list? How can i reset the list to the selected value

```
 <option value="" disabled selected>Select staff</option>
```

???

(I am using Jquery 1.11.3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I changed all code to angluar style and used ng-change event instead of

```
$('#selectbox').change(function() {});
```

Like this:

```
<select name="comp" id="comp" ng-change="changeComp()">
<option value="" disabled selected>Select company</option>
<option value="Company1">Company1</option>
<option value="Company2">Company2</option>
</select>

<select name="dept" id="dept" ng-change="changeDept()">
<option value="" disabled selected>Select department</option>
<option value="All">All</option>
<option ng-repeat="department in departmentList" value="{{department}}">{{department}}</option>
</select>

<select name="staff" id="staff">
<option value="" disabled selected>Select staff</option>
<option value="All">All</option>
<option ng-repeat="staff in staffList" value="{{staff}}">{{staff}}</option>
</select>
```

and the Jscript:

```
 $scope.changeComp = function(){
        $scope.editForm.dept = '';
        $scope.changeDept();

};

$scope.changeDept = function(){
        $scope.editForm.staff = '';
    };
```

Furthermore i was updating the source of the 3rd selectbox 2 times in code instead of only one time, this has added a blank entry to the select list.

Answer (score 0):

In your actual code, did you add a quotation mark after the "staff" value of the name attribute of the third select tag? unless you did not copy+pasted your code to here, this will definitely debug it, as name=value pairs are essential to form submission.

Comment: i corrected the code, in my actual source i don't have this issue, maybe i accidentally deleted it, but it did not solve the problem

Comment: k, im sorry, but soon someone with sufficient experience with the actual language of javascript will come to your aid.      until then, have a good evening.

Answer (score 0):

change

name="staff id="staff"

to

name="staff" id="staff"

you forgot to close the name

Comment: thanks, i corrected the code. i accidentally removed the quotation when i was editing the post before but it did not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

how about change it to function?

```
function selectBox1() {
    $("#comp").change(function() {
        $('#dept').val(''); 
        $('#staff').val('');
    });
}

function selectBox2() {
    $("#dept").change(function() {
        $('#staff').val('');
    });
    selectBox1();
}
selectBox1();
selectBox2();
$('#staff').change(function() {
    selectBox1();
    selectBox2();
});
```

Comment: then the 3rd selectbox will not update anymore if i select an item from the 2nd selectbox

Comment: have u try to do this?

Comment: yes i tried it, if i put the changed event into an function how can i call it when i change the value, for example, in the second select box ($("#dept"))?

Comment: i've update the code. forgot to call the function. how about now? can it works?

Comment: i just tried it, i still have the same behavior that when i set  $('#staff').val(''); it adds a <option value="? string:staff name ?"></option> ==$0